# Prevent Windows Store app opening from Apps website

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store-app

When viewing an app on the [Windows Apps website](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb), the full-screen (Metro) Windows Store app always opens on my PC.

**How do I stop this ridiculous behavior?** How do I prevent the Windows Store app from opening, just because I happen to view an app on their website -- *which I obviously prefer, since I chose to use the website instead of the Store app in the first place*?

Comment: I'm a desktop user, and generally despise Metro apps, but there are a couple that I've found useful; however the Windows Store app in particular really irritates me -- as does this unwanted, unexpected, and utterly non-intuitive behavior of jumping away from a perfectly good web page to the full-screen Store view. It's very bad UX, imho, but I'm really hoping Windows 10 will live up to the hype and bring back the classic *(read: usable)* desktop experience... for those few of us *(Microsoft apparently believes)* who still use Windows on a PC.

Comment: Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 while similar which one you are using will effect the answer to this question.